# lvconvert creating cached LV - results in device-mapper: reload ioctl on (254:0) failed: Invalid argument

Tags: lvm, device-mapper, ioctl

On Sles15, after successfully creating the Meta and Cache LVs and combining them with `lvconvert`, I then go to associate the Cachepool with the slow LV and get the following error:

> lvconvert --type cache --cachepool vgVMs9/VMs9Cache vgVMs9/VMs9
>   Do you want wipe existing metadata of cache pool vgVMs9/VMs9Cache? [y/n]: y
>
> device-mapper: reload ioctl on  (254:0) failed: Invalid argument
>   Failed to lock logical volume vgVMs9/VMs9.

I have successfully done this on another identical SLES15 system in exactly the same way using

```
http://fibrevillage.com/storage/460-how-to-create-lvm-cache-logical-volume
```

The failing system has had a number of LV's and VG's removed and added and so I suspect there is an issue with the LV Metadata, but I cannot discover where.

Everything looks ok when I look at the following before re-creating the vg or lv from scratch. I've even destroyed the physical array and re-created it to a different sd.

When I try and create the cache to the other two LV's I also get the same error.

Any help on the next move would be gratefully appreciated.

Here is the strace of another attempt with a different raid array and SSD's

```
getpid()                                = 5618
write(3, "request=\"set_vg_info\"\nname =\"vgV"..., 168) = 168
write(3, "\n##\n", 4)                   = 4
read(3, "response = \"OK\"\n\n##\n", 32) = 20
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3eLye3Owz2DWkLRxe4I1zjQcj4BbellM8", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x3), name="vgVMs8-VMs8", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3eLye3Owz2DWkLRxe4I1zjQcj4BbellM8", target_count=1, open_count=1, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(4, BLKRAGET, [1024])              = 0
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3eLye3Owz2DWkLRxe4I1zjQcj4BbellM8", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x3), name="vgVMs8-VMs8", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3eLye3Owz2DWkLRxe4I1zjQcj4BbellM8", target_count=1, open_count=1, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(7, DM_TABLE_DEPS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x3), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=328, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x3), name="vgVMs8-VMs8", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3eLye3Owz2DWkLRxe4I1zjQcj4BbellM8", target_count=1, open_count=1, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG, ...}) = 0
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3eLye3Owz2DWkLRxe4I1zjQcj4BbellM8-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3eLye3Owz2DWkLRxe4I1zjQcj4BbellM8-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3eLye3Owz2DWkLRxe4I1zjQcj4BbellM8-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3eLye3Owz2DWkLRxe4I1zjQcj4BbellM8-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bFJubP7pbpQw7iPMn262W7N1KuvGMl6q-cdata", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bFJubP7pbpQw7iPMn262W7N1KuvGMl6q-cdata", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bFJubP7pbpQw7iPMn262W7N1KuvGMl6q", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bFJubP7pbpQw7iPMn262W7N1KuvGMl6q", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bFJubP7pbpQw7iPMn262W7N1KuvGMl6q-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bFJubP7pbpQw7iPMn262W7N1KuvGMl6q-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bFJubP7pbpQw7iPMn262W7N1KuvGMl6q-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bFJubP7pbpQw7iPMn262W7N1KuvGMl6q-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bovUpaCpxkuLemqdSnYbwhPCJCk3IQW0-cmeta", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bovUpaCpxkuLemqdSnYbwhPCJCk3IQW0-cmeta", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bovUpaCpxkuLemqdSnYbwhPCJCk3IQW0", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bovUpaCpxkuLemqdSnYbwhPCJCk3IQW0", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bovUpaCpxkuLemqdSnYbwhPCJCk3IQW0-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bovUpaCpxkuLemqdSnYbwhPCJCk3IQW0-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bovUpaCpxkuLemqdSnYbwhPCJCk3IQW0-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bovUpaCpxkuLemqdSnYbwhPCJCk3IQW0-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3T4bBHXZZ32yNW3bDsH63EzotPO07kjW4-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3T4bBHXZZ32yNW3bDsH63EzotPO07kjW4-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3T4bBHXZZ32yNW3bDsH63EzotPO07kjW4-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3T4bBHXZZ32yNW3bDsH63EzotPO07kjW4-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3T4bBHXZZ32yNW3bDsH63EzotPO07kjW4-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3T4bBHXZZ32yNW3bDsH63EzotPO07kjW4-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
stat("/dev/sdh", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x70), ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/sdh", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x70), ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/sdh", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x70), ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/sdh", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x70), ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/sdf", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x50), ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/sdf", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x50), ...}) = 0
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_CREATE, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, name="vgVMs8-VMs8Cache_cdata", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bFJubP7pbpQw7iPMn262W7N1KuvGMl6q-cdata", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x4), name="vgVMs8-VMs8Cache_cdata", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bFJubP7pbpQw7iPMn262W7N1KuvGMl6q-cdata", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(7, DM_TABLE_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x4), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x4), name="vgVMs8-VMs8Cache_cdata", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bFJubP7pbpQw7iPMn262W7N1KuvGMl6q-cdata", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(7, DM_TABLE_LOAD, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x4), target_count=1, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG, ...} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x4), name="vgVMs8-VMs8Cache_cdata", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bFJubP7pbpQw7iPMn262W7N1KuvGMl6q-cdata", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_INACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
semget(0xd4d698c, 1, 000)               = 1638400
semop(1638400, [{0, 1, 0}], 1)          = 0
semctl(1638400, 0, GETVAL, NULL)        = 2
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_SUSPEND, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x4), event_nr=7235980, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x4), name="vgVMs8-VMs8Cache_cdata", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bFJubP7pbpQw7iPMn262W7N1KuvGMl6q-cdata", target_count=1, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG|DM_UEVENT_GENERATED_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_CREATE, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, name="vgVMs8-VMs8Cache_cmeta", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bovUpaCpxkuLemqdSnYbwhPCJCk3IQW0-cmeta", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x6), name="vgVMs8-VMs8Cache_cmeta", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bovUpaCpxkuLemqdSnYbwhPCJCk3IQW0-cmeta", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(7, DM_TABLE_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x6), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x6), name="vgVMs8-VMs8Cache_cmeta", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bovUpaCpxkuLemqdSnYbwhPCJCk3IQW0-cmeta", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(7, DM_TABLE_LOAD, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x6), target_count=1, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG, ...} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x6), name="vgVMs8-VMs8Cache_cmeta", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bovUpaCpxkuLemqdSnYbwhPCJCk3IQW0-cmeta", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_INACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
semget(0xd4d698c, 1, 000)               = 1638400
semop(1638400, [{0, 1, 0}], 1)          = 0
semctl(1638400, 0, GETVAL, NULL)        = 3
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_SUSPEND, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x6), event_nr=7235980, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x6), name="vgVMs8-VMs8Cache_cmeta", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3bovUpaCpxkuLemqdSnYbwhPCJCk3IQW0-cmeta", target_count=1, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG|DM_UEVENT_GENERATED_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_CREATE, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, name="vgVMs8-VMs8_corig", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3T4bBHXZZ32yNW3bDsH63EzotPO07kjW4-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x7), name="vgVMs8-VMs8_corig", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3T4bBHXZZ32yNW3bDsH63EzotPO07kjW4-real", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(7, DM_TABLE_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x7), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x7), name="vgVMs8-VMs8_corig", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3T4bBHXZZ32yNW3bDsH63EzotPO07kjW4-real", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(7, DM_TABLE_LOAD, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x7), target_count=1, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG, ...} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x7), name="vgVMs8-VMs8_corig", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3T4bBHXZZ32yNW3bDsH63EzotPO07kjW4-real", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_INACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
semget(0xd4d698c, 1, 000)               = 1638400
semop(1638400, [{0, 1, 0}], 1)          = 0
semctl(1638400, 0, GETVAL, NULL)        = 4
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_SUSPEND, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x7), event_nr=7235980, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x7), name="vgVMs8-VMs8_corig", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3T4bBHXZZ32yNW3bDsH63EzotPO07kjW4-real", target_count=1, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG|DM_UEVENT_GENERATED_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(7, DM_TABLE_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x3), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=362, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x3), name="vgVMs8-VMs8", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3eLye3Owz2DWkLRxe4I1zjQcj4BbellM8", target_count=1, open_count=1, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG, ...}) = 0
ioctl(7, DM_TABLE_LOAD, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x3), target_count=1, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG, ...} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x3), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(2, "  ", 2  )                       = 2
write(2, "device-mapper: reload ioctl on  "..., 64device-mapper: reload ioctl on  (254:3) failed: Invalid argument) = 64
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(2, "  ", 2  )                       = 2
write(2, "Failed to lock logical volume vg"..., 42Failed to lock logical volume vgVMs8/VMs8.) = 42
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
lseek(4, 4096, SEEK_SET)                = 4096
read(4, "Dk8\351 LVM2 x[5A%r0N*>\1\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(4, 32768, SEEK_SET)               = 32768
read(4, "vgVMs8 {\nid = \"cjMY1E-8tJM-jtgY-"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(4, 4096, SEEK_SET)                = 4096
read(4, "Dk8\351 LVM2 x[5A%r0N*>\1\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(4, 4096, SEEK_SET)                = 4096
write(4, "\320\252\353\16 LVM2 x[5A%r0N*>\1\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
brk(0x55e34c8a1000)                     = 0x55e34c8a1000
lseek(6, 4096, SEEK_SET)                = 4096
read(6, "Hj\260\313 LVM2 x[5A%r0N*>\1\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(6, 24576, SEEK_SET)               = 24576
read(6, "vgVMs8 {\nid = \"cjMY1E-8tJM-jtgY-"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(6, 4096, SEEK_SET)                = 4096
read(6, "Hj\260\313 LVM2 x[5A%r0N*>\1\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(6, 4096, SEEK_SET)                = 4096
write(6, "\252\260\f\203 LVM2 x[5A%r0N*>\1\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3eLye3Owz2DWkLRxe4I1zjQcj4BbellM8", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.37.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfe, 0x3), name="vgVMs8-VMs8", uuid="LVM-cjMY1E8tJMjtgYSU23u1Ybg2iNY831m3eLye3Owz2DWkLRxe4I1zjQcj4BbellM8", target_count=1, open_count=1, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
semget(0xd4d698c, 1, 000)               = 1638400
semctl(1638400, 0, GETVAL, NULL)        = 1
semop(1638400, [{0, -1, IPC_NOWAIT}], 1) = 0
semop(1638400, [{0, 0, 0}], 1)          = 0
semctl(1638400, 0, IPC_RMID, NULL)      = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/254:4/bdi/read_ahead_kb", O_RDONLY) = 8
read(8, "512\n", 23)                    = 4
close(8)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/254:6/bdi/read_ahead_kb", O_RDONLY) = 8
read(8, "512\n", 23)                    = 4
close(8)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/254:7/bdi/read_ahead_kb", O_RDONLY) = 8
read(8, "512\n", 23)                    = 4
close(8)                                = 0
close(7)                                = 0
flock(5, LOCK_NB|LOCK_UN)               = 0
flock(5, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)               = 0
stat("/run/lock/lvm/V_vgVMs8", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0700, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0700, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
unlink("/run/lock/lvm/V_vgVMs8")        = 0
close(5)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
brk(0x55e34c89d000)                     = 0x55e34c89d000
brk(0x55e34c899000)                     = 0x55e34c899000
brk(0x55e34c895000)                     = 0x55e34c895000
fcntl(0, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(0, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8402 (flags O_RDWR|O_APPEND|O_LARGEFILE)
dup(0)                                  = 4
close(0)                                = 0
dup2(4, 0)                              = 0
close(4)                                = 0
fcntl(0, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8402 (flags O_RDWR|O_APPEND|O_LARGEFILE)
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(1, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8402 (flags O_RDWR|O_APPEND|O_LARGEFILE)
dup(1)                                  = 4
close(1)                                = 0
dup2(4, 1)                              = 1
close(4)                                = 0
fcntl(1, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8402 (flags O_RDWR|O_APPEND|O_LARGEFILE)
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(5)                           = ?
+++ exited with 5 +++
```